# Simple request stalled in chrome for long time

Tags: http, networking, request, google-chrome-devtools

Ths is a simple get request which returns two small files. The content downloads in 2.71 ms. But, the request finish time is 4.15 seconds. Chrome tools show it the request is stalled. This is not queued, and this has less than 6 connections. What is the reason to be stalled ?

[image]

```
  t=88458 [st=  16]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=88458 [st=  16]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=88458 [st=  16]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=3408]
t=88458 [st=  16]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                         --> source_dependency = 532266 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=91866 [st=3424]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                         --> source_dependency = 532267 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=91866 [st=3424]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=91867 [st=3425]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=91867 [st=3425]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=293]
t=91867 [st=3425]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                         --> source_dependency = 532317 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=92160 [st=3718]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                         --> source_dependency = 532318 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=92160 [st=3718]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=92160 [st=3718]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=92160 [st=3718]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?